# Min per row in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table with 4 columns of type `timestamp tz` in PrestoDB - no NULL values - and am unable to get the min value per row.  It seems counter intuitive because:

```
SELECT
(SELECT MIN(Col) FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)) AS X(Col)) AS TheMin
FROM mytable
```

^ using fake integer will return 1 for all rows

Yet in my table:

[image]

```
SELECT
(SELECT MIN(Col) FROM (VALUES (_col2), (_col3), (_col4), (_col5)) AS X(Col)) AS TheMin
FROM mytable
```

returns `Presto query has failed. type cannot be null`

How is this possible when the data types in the columns are all `timestamp tz` and there are zero NULL values ?

What is the workaround here for finding the min timestamp per row using the columns as `VALUES` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `LEAST()`:

```
SELECT LEAST(_col2, _col3, _col4), _col5) as TheMin
FROM mytable
```